# Sketching Inverse Functions

Tags: functions

I have to find the inverse of the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, where $x \geq 3$. However in the answer, the coordinates seem to be given as $(3,1)$. Shouldn't it be $(3,\frac{1}{3})$? Or is it that since it's a sketch, it's just an estimation of how the functions would look like and so it doesn't have to be 'accurate'? 
I've just started doing these and I'm a bit confused on how I'm supposed to sketch these reflections.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

When doing the inverse of a function the x-values and y-values are swapped. This would make sense why your answer would be (3,1) rather than (3,1/3).

Another thing that is important to remember is that the inverse is relfected about the line y=x. Just something to keep in mind!

Comment: (3,1) is given as the coordinate of the original function, i.e. f(x) = 1/x, how could it's coordinates be such?

Comment: What is the question exactly asking? Are you supposed to sketch the graph or just determine whether it is an inverse? The inverse point of (3,1) is (1,3) because the inverse is merely swapping the x's and y's of every point in the function.

Comment: It's asking me to sketch the inverses keeping in mind the domain. I'm confused about the coordinates as f(3) = 1/3 not 1. I understand that you'd have to reflect the graph about the line y=x, but the coordinates don't seem to match.